# VB.NET how i can calculate late time in datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, datagridview

i need help calculate late time with on duty - clock in but my code wont work,
this actualy not clock in - clock out i put that just for example.\

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmExcelGrid.Rows
        Dim clock1 As DateTime
        Dim clock2 As DateTime
        Dim total As TimeSpan
        clock1 = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells("clock in").Value)
        clock2 = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells("clock out").Value)
        total = clock1 - clock2
        row.Cells("total").Value = total
     Next


End Sub
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6XM5.jpg)

Comment: What exactly does total show? Right now your total will always be a `negative time` because you are substracting the later date from the earlier. 
`10:00 - 16:00 = -6:00`
`16:00-10:00 = 6`

Comment: my problem is eror in that code i never done calculate that. "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to subtract the clock in from the clock out (otherwise you may have a negative timespan).

Value of a DataGridView Cell is an object, so you might need a .ToString before parsing it to a DateTime.

You may also need a `.ToString()`: when setting the `Value`

```
    Dim clockIn = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells("clock in").Value.ToString())
    Dim clockOut = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells("clock out").Value.ToString())
    Dim total = clockOut - clockIn
    row.Cells("total").Value = total.ToString()
```

If that DateTime.Parse does not work, you will have to look into `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: this eror still show "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Oh - well now you have posted the error that is a different issue